# How to correctly save a dictionary in .npz format

Tags: python, numpy

I am writing a program that loads an npz file, makes some changes to the values and stores it again. The .npz file varies in shape (dimensions).

I have gotten to the point where I can do everything, with exception that the individual numpy arrays are out of order.

Code flow:

```
data = dict(np.load(my_npz_file))

#Do some changes to dictionary

data_to_store = [data[layer] for layer in data]
np.savez(output_npz_file, *data_to_store)
```

However the problem is this, ordering is lost.

Print code:

```
keys=data.keys()
    for i,h in enumerate(keys):
        print "i="+str(i)+"h="+str(h)+"shape="+str(np.shape(data[h]))
```

Data read in format:

```
i=0h=arr_24shape=(128, 32, 3, 3)
i=1h=arr_25shape=(128,)
i=2h=arr_26shape=(48, 256, 1, 1)
i=3h=arr_27shape=(48,)
i=4h=arr_20shape=(32, 256, 1, 1)
i=5h=arr_21shape=(32,)
i=6h=arr_22shape=(128, 32, 1, 1)
i=7h=arr_23shape=(128,)
i=8h=arr_28shape=(192, 48, 1, 1)
i=9h=arr_29shape=(192,)
i=10h=arr_46shape=(256, 64, 1, 1)
i=11h=arr_47shape=(256,)
i=12h=arr_44shape=(64, 512, 1, 1)
i=13h=arr_45shape=(64,)
i=14h=arr_42shape=(256, 64, 3, 3)
i=15h=arr_43shape=(256,)
i=16h=arr_40shape=(256, 64, 1, 1)
i=17h=arr_41shape=(256,)
i=18h=arr_48shape=(256, 64, 3, 3)
i=19h=arr_49shape=(256,)
i=20h=arr_33shape=(48,)
i=21h=arr_32shape=(48, 384, 1, 1)
i=22h=arr_31shape=(192,)
i=23h=arr_30shape=(192, 48, 3, 3)
i=24h=arr_37shape=(192,)
i=25h=arr_36shape=(192, 48, 3, 3)
i=26h=arr_35shape=(192,)
i=27h=arr_34shape=(192, 48, 1, 1)
i=28h=arr_39shape=(64,)
i=29h=arr_38shape=(64, 384, 1, 1)
i=30h=arr_19shape=(128,)
i=31h=arr_18shape=(128, 32, 3, 3)
i=32h=arr_51shape=(1000,)
i=33h=arr_50shape=(1000, 512, 1, 1)
i=34h=arr_11shape=(64,)
i=35h=arr_10shape=(64, 16, 1, 1)
i=36h=arr_13shape=(64,)
i=37h=arr_12shape=(64, 16, 3, 3)
i=38h=arr_15shape=(32,)
i=39h=arr_14shape=(32, 128, 1, 1)
i=40h=arr_17shape=(128,)
i=41h=arr_16shape=(128, 32, 1, 1)
i=42h=arr_1shape=(96,)
i=43h=arr_0shape=(96, 3, 7, 7)
i=44h=arr_3shape=(16,)
i=45h=arr_2shape=(16, 96, 1, 1)
i=46h=arr_5shape=(64,)
i=47h=arr_4shape=(64, 16, 1, 1)
i=48h=arr_7shape=(64,)
i=49h=arr_6shape=(64, 16, 3, 3)
i=50h=arr_9shape=(16,)
i=51h=arr_8shape=(16, 128, 1, 1)
```

Data output format:

```
i=0h=arr_24shape=(192,)
i=1h=arr_25shape=(192, 48, 3, 3)
i=2h=arr_26shape=(192,)
i=3h=arr_27shape=(192, 48, 1, 1)
i=4h=arr_20shape=(48,)
i=5h=arr_21shape=(48, 384, 1, 1)
i=6h=arr_22shape=(192,)
i=7h=arr_23shape=(192, 48, 3, 3)
i=8h=arr_28shape=(64,)
i=9h=arr_29shape=(64, 384, 1, 1)
i=10h=arr_46shape=(64,)
i=11h=arr_47shape=(64, 16, 1, 1)
i=12h=arr_44shape=(16,)
i=13h=arr_45shape=(16, 96, 1, 1)
i=14h=arr_42shape=(96,)
i=15h=arr_43shape=(96, 3, 7, 7)
i=16h=arr_40shape=(128,)
i=17h=arr_41shape=(128, 32, 1, 1)
i=18h=arr_48shape=(64,)
i=19h=arr_49shape=(64, 16, 3, 3)
i=20h=arr_33shape=(1000, 512, 1, 1)
i=21h=arr_32shape=(1000,)
i=22h=arr_31shape=(128, 32, 3, 3)
i=23h=arr_30shape=(128,)
i=24h=arr_37shape=(64, 16, 3, 3)
i=25h=arr_36shape=(64,)
i=26h=arr_35shape=(64, 16, 1, 1)
i=27h=arr_34shape=(64,)
i=28h=arr_39shape=(32, 128, 1, 1)
i=29h=arr_38shape=(32,)
i=30h=arr_19shape=(256,)
i=31h=arr_18shape=(256, 64, 3, 3)
i=32h=arr_51shape=(16, 128, 1, 1)
i=33h=arr_50shape=(16,)
i=34h=arr_11shape=(256,)
i=35h=arr_10shape=(256, 64, 1, 1)
i=36h=arr_13shape=(64,)
i=37h=arr_12shape=(64, 512, 1, 1)
i=38h=arr_15shape=(256,)
i=39h=arr_14shape=(256, 64, 3, 3)
i=40h=arr_17shape=(256,)
i=41h=arr_16shape=(256, 64, 1, 1)
i=42h=arr_1shape=(128,)
i=43h=arr_0shape=(128, 32, 3, 3)
i=44h=arr_3shape=(48,)
i=45h=arr_2shape=(48, 256, 1, 1)
i=46h=arr_5shape=(32,)
i=47h=arr_4shape=(32, 256, 1, 1)
i=48h=arr_7shape=(128,)
i=49h=arr_6shape=(128, 32, 1, 1)
i=50h=arr_9shape=(192,)
i=51h=arr_8shape=(192, 48, 1, 1)
```

As you can see, no data is lost, but it has gotten out of order.

Comment: Show the print code.  The source of the names is unclear.

Comment: Oh sorry. Will update.

Comment: `data_to_store` is a list, not a dictionary.  The names are then autogenerated

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's because at the beginning you convert the data to a dictionary:

```
data = dict(np.load(my_npz_file))
```

Dictionaries don't preserve order in Python ([at least in your Python version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/dictionaries-are-ordered-in-python-3-6)), but you can use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

---

Update: the exact problem is here...

```
data_to_store = [data[layer] for layer in data]
np.savez(output_npz_file, *data_to_store)
```

you make a list of all the layers in data, then iterate over them in a random order and write them into the file. So what was previously called `arr_0` will now be for example `arr_23` because that's how it can end up in a random traversal of data, and `np.savez` will just assign new, sequential names.

But you can also provide your own names to `np.savez` which will simplify your code a lot:

```
np.savez(output_npz_file, **data)  # data is a dict here
```

This will save each layer with the same name as it had originally.

Comment: So if i use an ordered dict, then it should all be preserved?

What's odd is I print out that ordering from my dictionary and it seems preserved there?

Comment: what's your Python version?

Comment: Hmm, not just the order that is lost: your output suggests that different keys map to different values...

Comment: Python 2.7.13

And the keys I believe are automatically generated by the savez() function? No?

Comment: Okay, so this version will have random ordering on dicts. Yes, keys are automatically generated if you pass *args, but you can define them if you pass **kwargs

Comment: The problem with the later (defining them) is that my .npz file varies from ~50-200 subarrays. So **kwargs would require defining 50+ subarrays, right?

Or is there a short hand way to do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153703/discussion-between-kos-and-karl-taht).